# How to login ethereum account by privateKey via web3?

Tags: node.js, express, ethereum, blockchain, web3js

Im creating a simple ethereum network and connect via web3js but i dont find any function to find address from privateKey, I use web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAddress, but it create a new account with balance 0 while exist address with this privatekey have balance 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use [web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth-accounts.html#privatekeytoaccount).

```
web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x348ce564d427...');

> {
      address: '0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cDe8e3bBed6568B2Fa01',
      privateKey: '0x348ce564d427...',
      signTransaction: function(tx){...},
      sign: function(data){...},
      encrypt: function(password){...}
  }
```